# Disable form validation in MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, validation, webforms

Is it possible to programatically disable form validation in MVC2?

I'm hoping there is some kind of command that I can put in a custom ActionMethodSelectorAttribute, making it possible to prefix ActionResults where I want form validation disabled.

The reason for this is that I have a form with multiple buttons, one button adds a new row to a child object of the model - which consequently creates a new row on the form.

This works fine, but validation is fired for the form each time "add" is pressed, and so the new fields flag up validation errors before the user has a chance to enter data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found an alternative solution to this.

Rather than use multiple form buttons, I've used a custom html helper which produces a "Add" link.
This helper places the current Model in TempData and produces a Link to Add/{id}.

I'm not sure this is the cleanest solution, but it allows child elements to be added without validation firing. To tidy things up a bit, I specified the form as such:

`Html.BeginForm(view, controller, new { id = Model.ID })`